# basis for topological manifold that intersections are path(or simply) connected

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I read from [Number of components of intersection of coordinate balls.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118904/number-of-components-of-intersection-of-coordinate-balls) that given arbitrary second countable basis $\mathcal{B}$ of a topological manifold $M$ consisting open subsets homeomorphic to open balls, the intersection of any two of them may not be path connected.

However, is there some well choosed basis such that the intersections do be path connected, or even simply connected? I think the answer for dimension one and two should be true for the classification of such topological manifolds. Nevertheless I cannot figure out if it's positive or not for the general cases.

Comment: I think it is unknown for 4-dimensional topological manifolds. In all other dimensions and for smooth and for triangulable manifolds the answer is positive. How much manifold topology do you know?

Comment: Just at the introductory level of the content like Lee's Topological Manifolds, or Smooth Manifolds. Knowing the results is nice too. Thank you very much @MoisheKohan

Comment: I see, then you are not ready for a substantive answer. Try to prove your conjecture for compact manifolds of dimension 1 and 2 using their classification. Now, try to prove it for surfaces without using the classification just to get an idea of how hard this problem is.